# ufw is not working properly

Tags: networking, server, firewall

I'm trying to enable `ufw` in remote ubuntu server. This server has two `LXC` container running. One container has nginx server running and I have hosted web application, right now every thing is working fine. I did port forwarding to access webapp of container from local system. I wanted to allow only 80 and 22 to be accessible through firewall, remaining all won't be allowed. These are the rules I did

```
# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         DENY IN     Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
```

after I enable the firewall with port 80 DENY I still be able to access the webapp of the container.

```
# iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:10.0.3.2:80

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.3.0/24         !10.0.3.0/24
```

Again to check whether firewall is working or not I tried use `scp`, `scp` will use port 21. As my firewall in ubuntu server is enable I shouldn't allow to copy file to server but I can able to copy files. check this

```
# scp /home/Attributes123.csv root@myserver:/home/ 
root@myserver's password:  
Attributes123.csv  100%    0    0.0KB/s   00:00
```

So my firewall setup is not working. any idea why it is not working?
I did reboot after enable firewall but no luck.

Comment: scp by default use port 22. Also you don't need `80  DENY IN  Anywhere` because is `Default: deny (incoming)`

Comment: Also your `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)` must be DROP. Something is wrong.

Comment: @2707974: If I do `sudo iptables -t nat -L`, then all of the default policies are `ACCEPT`, whereas if I do `sudo iptables -L`, the INPUT chain default is `DROP`.